# Rename a function after resizing screen

Tags: javascript, html

is possible to change a name of a function after resizing screen?

I have this

```
<div id="box1" data-same-height="blocks-resize">
```

where

```
data-same-height="blocks-resize"
```

is the function, and here's the javascript of that function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var equalize = function () {
    var disableOnMaxWidth = 0; // 767 for bootstrap

    var grouped = {};
    var elements = $('*[data-same-height]');

    elements.each(function () {
        var el = $(this);
        var id = el.attr('data-same-height');

        if (!grouped[id]) {
            grouped[id] = [];
        }

        grouped[id].push(el);
    });

    $.each(grouped, function (key) {
        var elements = $('*[data-same-height="' + key + '"]');

        elements.css('height', '');

        var winWidth = $(window).width();

        if (winWidth <= disableOnMaxWidth) {
            return;
        }

        var maxHeight = 0;

        elements.each(function () {
            var eleq = $(this);
            maxHeight = Math.max(eleq.height(), maxHeight);
        });

        elements.css('height', maxHeight + "px");
    });
};

var timeout = null;

$(window).resize(function () {
    if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(equalize, 250);
});
equalize();
```

});

It's possible to change that name (data-same-height) after resizing screen to 600px?  or could be also the "blocks-resize" too

Thanks!

Comment: while not an answer to your specific question, this may do what you're intending: http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Comment: FYI, you don't think the asterisk in $('*[data-same-height]'); and I think adding the asterisk here is going to make your selector much less performant unnecessarily

Comment: not sure if I'm understanding that page:( I just need my code to work until 600pixels wide, then I want to turn it off for a div to have his own auto size. @dward

Comment: change the function name or the attribute and value name in the element? either is possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
       $(function(){
          $(window).on("resize load", responsive);
       }) 

       var responsive = function() {
          if(window.innerWidth < 600) {
             //do your thing
          } else {
            //do something else.
         }
       }
```